# Underline Definitions in Index? (or keep formatting from orig. text)

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I'm building an index in a word document that is going to be definitions.  My index will look like:

> Superhero - someone who is a super being.....17
>  Bus - an
>   automobile that is long, like a wiener dog.....28
>  Cat - this is a
>   small animal.........17

etc...

In my document, the text looks like:

> And then there's a **Superhero** - someone who is a super being.

With "Superhero" being underlined (couldn't find how to underline, so I bolded for SO).

Is there a way to keep this underline when adding it to the index?  Alternatively, is there a way with VBA to scan through my Index, and underline text in each line that comes before the `-`?

Edit: The big idea is that I have a 120+ page document, which changes relatively frequently.  I have a macro that can scan the document, looking for definitions (defined as "[something] - means").  Then it adds those defintions to an Index, BUT it removes the underline that exists in the document.  I'd like to add it back in the index.

Perhaps I can scan for all definitions, as I do when adding to the index, and check to see if the definition is in the last section of my document? How would I do that in VBA, as something like `If selection.section = activedocument.sections.count Then`, except you can't do `.Section` to see what section number I'm in.\

Here's some code I have. I got it working insofar as my Index is ONE SECTION LESS than the `activedocument.sections.count`, despite it being the last section. Anyways, this works and I can get to my text, but need to keep going to see how to underline only the first bits:

```
Sub underline_Index_Definitions()
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range
Dim rngXE As Word.Range

Dim numParas&
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
Set rngDoc = myDoc.Content
Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate

bFound = True

Debug.Print "You have : " & myDoc.Sections.Count & " sections."

With rngDoc.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = "- means"
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With

Do While bFound
bFound = rngDoc.Find.Execute
If bFound Then
    Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
    rngXE.Select
    If rngXE.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) = myDoc.Sections.Count - 1 Then
        rngXE.Select
    End If

End If 'bFound
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think there is a markdown underline. What have you tried already in VBA? Searching for your strings? Identifying the lines? The code for font changes?

Comment: @Raystafarian - So far I haven't tried much, except for looping through my entire (120+ pages) document, looking for `-` (which all definitions have).  How can I tell when I arrive at the Index? If I made sure my last index was a unique section, and the last section in the document, could I loop through it then somehow? `If [the found word].Section = activedocument.sections.count then` , except you can't do `[range].Section` to see what section it's in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it, albeit a little kludgily:

```
Sub underline_Index_Definitions()
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range
Dim rngXE As Word.Range

Dim numParas&
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
Set rngDoc = myDoc.Content
Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate

bFound = True

Debug.Print "You have : " & myDoc.Sections.Count & " sections."

With rngDoc.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = "- means"
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With

Do While bFound
bFound = rngDoc.Find.Execute
If bFound Then
    Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
    rngXE.Select
    If rngXE.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) = myDoc.Sections.Count - 1 Then
        'Found definition in the index
        Set rngXE = rngXE.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rngXE.Select

        'Now, starting with the first character, go until the - and underline
        Dim startC&, endC&, x&
        x = 0
        Do Until rngXE.Characters(x + 1) = "-"
            Debug.Print rngXE.Characters(x + 1)
            If (x + 1) > rngXE.Characters.Count Then Exit Do
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        Set rngXE = myDoc.Range(Start:=rngXE.Characters(1).Start, End:=rngXE.Characters(x).End)
        rngXE.Select
        rngXE.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    End If

End If 'bFound
Loop
End Sub
```

Basically, I know my Index is a new section, at the very end of the document. So, I just have the macro looking for `-` throughout the document, but only when it reaches the Index (determined by the `Activedocument.sections.count - 1`), loops through each paragraph and grabs text in front of the `-`.

If anyone has any tips/ideas, please let me know as I'm still learning Word VBA (perhaps obviously)

Comment: Why not use a dictionary/array to store the index that way you can check  as your go along?

Comment: @raystafarian - uhm, because I dont know about those! I assume that's different than the excel dictionaries?

Comment: No, you should be able to use a scripting dictionary - the same one you use in excel.

Comment: @Raystafarian - So I started down the using a dictionary rabbit hole, and it looks like it's a way cleaner option for what I was trying to do (not necessarily with this question here, but my main idea in general).  Instead of building an index (which I can only have one of, without getting too crazy/complicated), I can just make three dictionaries and then output those at the end of my document.  Seriously, thanks a zillion for that simple suggestion mate, cheers!!!!

Comment: It's great to hear that!